# How to use matlab for plotting functions that contain summations?

Tags: summation, matlab

I am having a terrible time trying to figure out how to plot this function in matlab:

$$\frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}\sin(4t) - \frac{2}{\pi} \sum\limits_{k=2,4,6,8}\frac{\cos(4kt)}{k^2-1}$$

I am not sure how to incorporate the summation.

Comment: Why? It is straightforward to write an expression with all 6 terms?

Comment: @copper.hat, that is the reason I asked this question. I do not have a great deal of experience with Matlab. Without the summation portion of this equation it is simple, but with it I am unsure. I don't know what to do with the summation, or how matlab handles them. All I could find was a symbolic summation which did not seem fitting for this.

Comment: Why don't you just add all terms instead of summing them by some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read the manuals and online tutorials. Since I'm in a mellow mood:

I did this in Octave so YMMV...

```
function y = f(t)
    y = 1/pi+1/2*sin(4*t);
    for k = 2:2:8
        y = y-2/pi*cos(4*k*t)/(k^2-1);
    endfor
endfunction
```

Then do something like:

```
t = 0:.1:10;
plot(t, f(t))
# or Conrad's suggestion...
fplot(@f,[0,10])
```

Comment: @ConradTurner: Thanks! I can't bring myself to pay for a Matlab license. I used to use Moler's free Fortran version...

Comment: fplot works in Octave (at least it does in v3.8.x) ">> fplot(@sin,[0,1]);" works for me. Which suggests the call in by earlier comment is wrong and should have been either fplot(@f,[0,10]) or fplot("f(x)",[0,10]) (I'm not at my machine with Matlab at present to check, but rereading the online help it does say the first argument should be a function handle).

Comment: fplot(@f,[0,10]) seems to work fine in Octave...

Comment: I think the OP was thinking in terms of using fplot, which now you have defined the function would look like fplot(@f,[0,10]) -edited to correct the function call

Comment: Better to use `sum` than a for loop?

Comment: @A.Donda: I am only familiar with using sum for adding the elements of an array, what were you thinking? (Aside: How did you highlight sum?)

Comment: I mean vectorizing the code: `k = 2:2:8; y = 1/pi+1/2*sin(4*t) - 2/pi*sum(cos(4*k*t)./(k.^2-1));`.

Comment: @A.Donda: Thanks. I think it is a little harder to read for a toy example. How did you highlight the code in your comment?

Comment: use the backtick `

Comment: @A.Donda: `Thanks!`